# How to add CSS to this PHP statement?

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, joomla

How do I add this css:

```
<div class="alert alert-error">
</div>
```

to this PHP code:

```
<?php echo this->element->error; ?>
```

their is a "$" next to "this" stack won't show it

I need it to only display if its active. I tried doing this:

```
<?php if ($element->error != '') :?>
<div class="alert alert-error"> 
<?php echo $element->error?>
</div>
<?php endif;?>
```

But it doesn't work

Image of error below:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNzFd.png

Comment: Did you mean to use `$this->element>error` in your if/echo statements?

Comment: `But it doesn't work` Can you be more specific? `<?php echo $element->error?>` is missing a `;`

Answer (score 2):

Try to create an if else condition with `isset`

```
  // if `$this->element->error` is TRUE or SET..
 <?php if(isset($this->element->error)){?>
    <div class="alert alert-error"> 
    <?php echo $this->$element->error;?>
    </div>
    <?php }?>
 // if not it will be just ignored
```

Comment: Ok adding $this in front of your second php statment gave me this: http://i.imgur.com/IUmbSJN.png

Comment: Now All i need is to hide the empty alert boxes, for the rest of the non errors

Comment: @NickN you should include the alertbox div inside your statement

Comment: That was my main objective, just didn;t know exactly how

Comment: Yea I had this already, notice first image, I need the alert boxes under the other elements to not be there. This is a foreach so it puts empty alerts now under all elements if one has an error.

Comment: so the if statement spits out the css for the other elements, I need the css in the <php echo $this->element->error;?>

Comment: could you explain it a bit clearly? :D  , is what are you trying to do is to remove the other empty alert box if no error was shown?

Comment: @NickN then you must put your whole code to see.. try  to use pastebin

Comment: codes seems ambigious to know were to find the one we trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if ($this->element->error != '') :?>
    <div class="alert alert-error"><?php echo $this->element->error;?></div>
<?php endif;?>
```

This worked. Notice the difference in my code from question. Thanks @Kaii for all your time.

Comment: A matter of $this in two places and a ";"